# Why console not output anything when trying to work by paserver which running on windows server core docker container?

Tags: docker, delphi, dockerfile, delphi-xe8, server-core

After start my app I could not see anything in console on docker container

My Docketfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ADD install_paserver.bat /install_paserver.bat
ADD setup_paserver.exe /setup_paserver.exe
WORKDIR /
RUN install_paserver.bat
EXPOSE 64211
CMD ["/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/PAServer/16.0/paserver.exe"]
```

After that I have created simple console app using Embarcadero XE8:

```
program paServerApp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  i: integer;
  msg: string;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    Writeln('Test');
    for i := 0 to 100 do
      Writeln(i);

    msg := 'World';
    msg := 'Hello World!';

    Writeln(msg);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Than I checked my connection with paserver than was been started in windows docker and got the message: "Connection to IP on port 64211 succeeded". After that I tryied to start my app and it seccesfully coppied my project to the default package (scratch-dir) on docker container and started but not output in console. Where I made a mistake ?

Comment: How do you know your program started and ended successfully?

Comment: In the Rad studio in Build tab I see Success message and Elapsed time. And I can debug my app